# Redirect to a specific URL after successful anonymous auth via Spring Security OAuth2 client

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, http-redirect

I use Spring Security's OAuth2 client auth with code grant type to do anonymous authentication.

The built-in `OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter` does a redirect after a successful auth of an anonymous principal.
It redirects to a URL obtained either via a request stored in a `RequestCache`, or uses the default url (`oauth2/code/{registrationId}`) stripped from query params.

The `OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter`'s code in question:

```java
String redirectUrl = authorizationResponse.getRedirectUri();
SavedRequest savedRequest = this.requestCache.getRequest(request, response);
if (savedRequest != null) {
    redirectUrl = savedRequest.getRedirectUrl();
    this.requestCache.removeRequest(request, response);
}
this.redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, redirectUrl);
```

I can leverage the request cache to store a request for the redirection. But the `RequestCache`'s interface doesn't let me specify arbitrary URL for the redirection, only use an existing (immutable) HttpServletRequest.

I need to do a redirect to a specific URL based on some business logic. How can I force an arbitrary redirect URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this by not specifying the redirect URL at all. Instead, I leveraged the authorization URL that the `OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter` uses by default.

I registered two RequestMappings in a RestController at the path `/authorize/oauth2/code/{providerId}`, one with `params = "!error"` and a second with `params = "error"`. Since the OAuth filters do nothing with the redirect request (since it is stripped from oauth params), these two mappings can be used as a Success and Failure authorization handlers.

On the other hand, I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/8120) in spring-security for supporting injectable `RequestCache`, that would enable proper proper redirection mechanism. The issue seems to be worked on right now, but contains two other possible workarounds.